# Annotation not working :@Size and @Valid

Tags: spring-mvc

Even though the respective jars included , and @Valid included at method level still `@Size` is not working.

```
public class TicketBinder {

    @Size(min=2,max=30,message="please enter values for ticketID between 2 and 30")
    private String ticketID;

    @Size(min=3,max=7)
    private String creator;

    private Date date;
    private String engg;

}
```

//From Controller class

```
   public ModelAndView success(@Valid @ModelAttribute("ticket")TicketBinder binder,BindingResult result) {

        ModelAndView mav;
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            mav= new ModelAndView("index");
            return mav;
        }              

        mav= new ModelAndView("success");
        return mav;  
    }
```

Comment: Your Assistance Plz